# Regex to match a specific parenthesis among multiple

Tags: ruby, regex

Take the String:
`"The only true (wisdom) is in knowing you know (nothing)"`
I want to extract `nothing`.

What I know about it:

- It will always be inside a parenthesis
- The parenthesis will always be the last element before the line-end: `$`

I first attempted to match it with 
`/\(.*\)$/`, but that obviously returned
`(wisdom) is in knowing you know (nothing)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use negative character group matching, like `[^...]`:

```
s = 'The only true (wisdom) is in knowing you know (nothing)'
s.match(/\(([^)]+)\)$/).captures
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/DzgOFEk6B_ifDMwV)

In this case, `nothing` is in the first sub-group match, but the entire regex technically matches `(nothing)`. To match exactly `nothing` as the *entire* match, use:

```
s = 'The only true (wisdom) is in knowing you know (nothing)'
s.match(/(?<=\()([^)]+)(?=\)$)/).captures
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bF1npBpp4QAU-HwA)

Comment: The last regex hurts my brain. It works clean though, except that it also returns the parentheses surrounding `nothing` as well.

Comment: @krystah I corrected a typo in the second regex; sorry about that. Please remember to accept an answer if you found this helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
s = 'The only true (wisdom) is in knowing you know (nothing)'
s.match(/\(([^)]+)\)$/).captures # => ["nothing"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `scan` to find all matches and then take the last one:

```
str = "The only true (wisdom) is in knowing you know (nothing)"
str.scan(/\((.+?)\)/).last
#=> "nothing"
```

Comment: Interesting, I haven't tried `scan` yet. However, is there no way to achieve this using regex only?

Comment: On second thought, this might not work in all conditions. You would get the last bracketed text, even if it is not at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **\z** which matches end of string. try

> \([a-z]+\)\z

Way simpler and will ignore everything else but what you need.

Test it here:

http://rubular.com/

Comment: To ignore parenthesis: (?:\()[a-z]+(?:\))\z . Not sure why no one is considering the \z

Answer (score 0):

It's even trickier if there's any chance of nesting. In that case you need some recursion:

```
"...knowing you know ((almost) nothing)"[/\(((?:[^()]*|\(\g<1>\))*)\)$/, 1]
#=> "(almost) nothing"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look ma, no regex!

```
s = 'The only true (wisdom) is in knowing you know (nothing)'

r = s.reverse
r[(r.index(')') + 1)...(r.index('('))].reverse
  #=> "nothing"
```